# How to add jQuery close button?

Tags: jquery, button

```
<script type="text/java script">    
$(function () {
        $(".box").click(function () {
            var $overlay = $(this).find(".overlay");
            if ($overlay.is(':visible')) {
                $overlay.fadeOut();
            } else {
                $overlay.fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my menu script click button show this menu.
How can I add close button?

Comment: Not an answer, but your `if-else` can be replaced with a `$overlay.fadeToggle()` to accomplish the same behavior.

Also, be sure to edit that `java script` to be just `javascript` (one word) in your script declaration for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('.closeButton').click(function(e) {
    var $overlay = $(this).find(".overlay");
    $overlay.fadeOut();
});
```

You could even go a step further and put that code into a function which you could call from both snippets of code for reusability...

```
function closeOverlay() {
    var $overlay = $(this).find(".overlay");
    $overlay.fadeOut();
}

$('.closeButton').click(function(e) {
    closeOverlay();
});

$(".box").click(function () {
    var $overlay = $(this).find(".overlay");
    if ($overlay.is(':visible')) {
        closeOverlay();
    } else {
        $overlay.fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: also have a look at `fadeToggle()` which will eliminate your if statement - `$overlay.fadeToggle();`